# How do I override an incorrectly defined SQLAlchemy table?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We use SQLAlchemy to read/write data, but not create tables (as it done by DBAs). Due to this, some of the definitions which are incorrect have not yet been caught (though it works for reads/writes).

Is there a way to override them for testing purposes (create tables on the fly etc.) without touching the original definition? A simple class-overriding doesn't seem to work, and I don't see any other solution to this problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Numeric, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    idn = Column(Numeric, primary_key=True)  # should be Integer
    code = Column(String, primary_key=True)  # should be unique (not primary)


class Product(Product):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}  # want to override, not extend

    idn = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
```

Comment: dont know if it work or not, maybe first create migration with current db schema, ie flask db migrate show no change and then change db model and do schema upgrade, that might work

Comment: Thanks @sahasrara62. I have an option to override all the classes already, so there are some not-so-DRY options :).

Comment: Started a discussion thread here: https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/Ga32a91giuE